# Exporting Layer to Feature Class is Incomplete without Error

Tags: arcmap, export, feature-class, memory

I have a CSV of 1.2 million records that I want export to a GDB as a feature class. I've done this numerous times, but this was before upgrading from 10.5. Steps:

1. Add CSV
2. Display X/Y table
3. Export to GDB

The result (without error) is a FC in the GDB, but with 234,000 records instead of the 1.2 million in the CSV. I also tried exporting it off as a shapefile, knowing that there's a 2GB limit on those. Is there something I need to change in the ArcMap config files to increase the memory? I see several posts out there about changing the machine's virtual memory, but I've never had to do that for this.

I'm running ArcMap 10.6.1 on a 64-bit Windows 10 Pro machine.

EDIT: I have to import the CSV to a GDB and then display the X/Y in order to make it work. I used to be able to just import the CSV and display XY off the bat.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is a memory issue. I would look at corruption in the CSV file.

Comment: Do you have 1,2 million records if you open the attribute table of the csv after adding it?

Comment: Yes, the raw count is correct when I add the CSV, just not after displaying the data as a X/Y layer